# copying a blob from mysql to postgres not going well (i don't see the image anymore)

Tags: c++, mysql, postgresql, copy, blob

i have to copy a blob image (jpeg) from mysql database to a postgres table with field bytea.
i use c++..i read image from mysql in this way

```
char* buffer = new char[res2->getInt(1)];
memset(buffer, '\0', res2->getInt(1));
(res->getBlob("att"))->read(buffer,res2->getInt(1));
```

res2 contains LENGHT(blob_field).
now if i save buffer on a file i see the image perfectly.
after that i write the buffer on postgres table with

```
const char* const paramValues[] = {buffer};
const int nParams = sizeof(paramValues) / sizeof(paramValues[0]);
const int paramLenghts[] = {buffer_size };
const int paramFormats[] = {1 }; /*binary */


PQexecParams(
             conn,
             "INSERT INTO images (img) VALUES($1::bytea)",
             nParams,
             NULL, /* Types of parameters, unused as casts will define types */
             paramValues,
             paramLenghts,
             paramFormats,
             0
         );
```

in postgres table i have data in bytea field, but if i copy and paste by hand on a file, i cannot see the images because it says is not a jpeg image...the postgres string is  different from the mysql one (if i open the mysql one with a text editor) but i don't understand why since i 've done a simple copy and paste..
any hint??

Comment: the _postgres string_  is presumably the text representation of the bytea contents. Just like you use C++ to insert the image, use C++ to extract it into a file as opposed to copy/paste from some unspecified vizualization tool.

Comment: i thought about this possibility..i used pgadmin...with mysql workbench i could see the direct image from table, but pgadmin doesn't offer this kind of stuff so i tried in that way..i'll try

Comment: @DanielVérité i tried to read with c++ and write to a file but the image is corrupt..and the string inside is exactly what i saw from pgadmin..plus the lenght of what i read from postgres is much longer than what i have on mysql: bytea filed is 19253 byte long,the original is 6728

Comment: update i tried to open it using java loading on a Image and it works so in postgres the data are correct

Answer (score 0):

Most likely escaping is what is causing your problem. Bytea can come back in text or binary mode.  If it is text mode you will see a hex string, or an octal escaped string.  In this case you need to run it through `PQunescapeBytea` first.

If that is not the problem, then the next step is to look at how you inserted the data.  It is possible you inserted it incorrectly and so your data in your database is corrupt.